# How to access react-native-maps marker by ID

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I've been doing a bit of research but I can't quite figure out how to grab the coordinates of a react-native-maps marker based off the id I give it. However when I run the code I get an "undefined is not an object" error

Here's the code

```
  const getBounds = () => {
    if (mapRef === null) {
      return;
    }
    mapRef
      .getMapBoundaries()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      console.log("Marker" , mapRef.markers["MyID"].showCallout());
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you use the ref.
If the markers are direct children of the MapView, you need to search for the markers in the .current.props.children array. If they are flat, it will be on array index 0, just print the thing with console.log to find out your exact children structure.
Something along the lines of:

```
mapRef.current.props.children[0].find(marker => marker.id = "MyID");
```

As a side not, why not reuse the key prop?